# OrientDB query all out edges

Tags: orientdb

I want to do a query in OrientDB but i don't know how it works.

I'm using the Graph API and my DB looks like this:

class(V): @route (Name, Start, Length, Goal) 
class(V): @direction (Goal, length)

class(E): @has_A
class(E): @start_Direction
class(E): @has_Follower

The Edges are connected to the Vertices like this: 
route -> has_A -> direction 
route -> start_Direction -> direction 
direction -> has_Follower -> direction

now i need to find all followers by the name of the route, 
what works so far is when i enter a rid (of the class startDirection) directly to the query for example:

```
select * from (traverse outE('has_Follower'),has_Follower.in from #??:?) where @class='direction'
```

But now i need to get to the rid over the Name of the route (which is the problem), what i tried so far is:

```
select * from (traverse outE('has_Follower'),has_Follower.in from (select @rid from start_Direction where start_Direction.out = (select @rid from route where Name = 'nameOfroute'))) where @class='direction'
```

But this gives me an empty query, although when i type in the rid from start_Direction of which i know has a has_Follower it works.

Hope this is understandable, thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Hi, could you add some example data? Thx

Answer (score 0):

One problem in your query is probably `start_Direction.out = (select...`, you have to use an `IN` instead of an `=`, eg `start_Direction.out IN (select...`.

In general, I think the easiest way to do what you need is as follows:

```
 MATCH
   {class:route, as:route} -start_Direction-> {} -has_Follower-> {as:direction, while:(true)}
 RETURN route.@rid, route.Name, route.Start, route.Length, route.Goal, direction.Goal, direction.length
```

Or just `RETURN $elements` if you want single records per row